# Make multiple queries to master tables of database using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity framework to manage all database operations.

In one particular screen of my application, I need to fetch data from many master tables which are unrelated to each other. In c# code, If i query each table seperately, it takes a lot of time and more than 10 queries which cannot be combined.

Is there an option where I can combine them to make a single database call but still continue using linq.

Currently I am doing

```
 var master1=await (from p in context.Master1
             select p).ToListAsync()

 var master2=await (from p in context.Master2
             select p).ToListAsync()

 var master3=await (from p in context.Master3
             select p).ToListAsync()
```

What is an alternative?

Comment: Only if you can project them all to one same (anonymous) type. Then you can use .Concat. But why can't you combine more than 10 queries? If it's because of timeouts then 10 queries in 1 call will even be worse.

Comment: See `WhenAll` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to scrape the data retrieval to only what is essential. Having a call that is querying 10 unrelated tables sounds like a poor design. If this is a case where you're fetching 10x lookups, consider re-factoring the design so that these are requested in smaller batches asynchronously (I.e. Ajax) as a page loads rather than all at once.

As far as loading the data, leverage projection rather than fetching entities. Often when I see code like this the first thing I look for is lazy-loading penalties. This would be cases where I see something as innocent looking as:

```
var viewModel = new SearchViewModel();

var products = await context.Products.ToListAsync();
viewModel.Products = products;

// ... repeat for other lookups...

return View(viewModel);
```

This sends up red flags.

1. Serializing entities will "touch" navigation properties resulting in lazy load hits.
2. Even if there aren't navigation properties, do we need all fields from the entities?
3. `async` isn't a performance silver bullet.

For items 1 & 2:
When loading data to return to a view, leverage projection to avoid lazy load surprises and minimize the amount of data being transmitted both from the DB and to the client. Lazy loading can make server calls ridiculously slow where the individual query debugs and runs fast, but you're waiting many seconds to even minutes before the page comes back. Hooking up an SQL Profiler on the database will reveal that after the method executes, hundreds, if not thousands of additional queries are hitting the database beyond the 10 or so you initially called. This is the serializer "touching" navigation properties, and it is a massive factor slower than if you'd eager-loaded all of the data. The solution to these issues is projection:

```
var viewModel = new SearchViewModel();

var products = await context.Products
    .Select(x => new ProductSummaryViewModel
    {
        ProductId = x.ProductId,
        Name = x.Name
    }).ToListAsync();
viewModel.Products = products;

// ... repeat for other lookups...

return View(viewModel);
```

You can simplify this even further by leveraging Automapper and it's `ProjectTo` method instead of `Select` which works with EF's `IQueryable`. Projection avoids lazy-load surprises and builds queries that only return the data you need.

For point #3: `async` does not make operations / calls faster, if anything it makes them marginally slower. What it does do is make your server code more responsive while it is busy fetching larger operations. Too often I see code structured as if `async` is an all-or-nothing decision. It has it's uses, but should be used sparingly where it can provide the most benefit. Fetching small sets or individual records by IDs don't benefit at all from being made asynchronously. If an operation doesn't take more than say 250ms to run, and isn't going to be called in a seriously high frequency on a massive multi-core microservice server I honestly wouldn't bother introducing the overhead of `async`.

Ultimately it comes down to ensuring you're only querying as much data as you absolutely need, then looking for further optimizations or restructuring the calls (i.e. Ajax, or breaking up your UI more atomically rather than everything on one screen) if there still is a responsiveness hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

```
var master1 = (from p in context.Master1
         select p).ToListAsync()

var master2 = (from p in context.Master2
         select p).ToListAsync()

var master3 = (from p in context.Master3
         select p).ToListAsync()

await Task.WhenAll(master1, master2, master3);
```

This won't be a single database call but will allow them to query the data without waiting on the previous statement.

The code will only continue past WhenAll when all of the tasks have completed